# how to locate API in getJSON call when site is not a root of its URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

To call ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API, I am using following convention to call its service

```
 $.getJSON("api/products/", ...
```

If my url of the site is a root such as `http://localhost:10234`, everything is fine.

But once the url became `http://localhost/SomeApp`, the ajax call failed because

.getJSON actually calls `http://localhost/api/products` instead of `http://localhost/SomeApp/api/products`. What should I do in this case to correct the location. "/api/products/" or "~/api/products" does not work.

Comment: your js code is in the same server with web api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the first part of my _Layout.cshtml, I put

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    appFolder = @Url.Content("~/");
</script>
```

and changed my call in javascripts to

```
$.getJSON(appFolder+"api/products/"
```

And this fixed the problem.